# C++: Bug in read file

Tags: c++

A newbie to C++ here. I'm trying to implement a mesh simplification algorithm in C++. I'm encountering some very strange thing here.

```
void Mesh::loadMF(const char* filename) {
    init();
    std::ifstream infile;
    infile.open(filename, std::ios::in);
    std::string strbuff;
    while (std::getline(infile, strbuff)) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << strbuff;
        char type;
        ss >> type;
        if (type == 'v') {
            Vertex* v;
            ss >> v->x >> v->y >> v->z;
            print(v->x);
            V.push_back(v);
        }
    }
    infile.close();
}
```

What the `loadMF` method of the `Mesh` class does is that it reads a .mesh file and loads the vertices that exist in this mesh.

The .mesh file has the following content:

```
v 3.201600 -1.456025 1.928155
v 3.520754 -1.658353 2.036948
v 3.121542 -1.461538 2.045325
v 3.020618 -1.278575 1.711228
f 1 2 3
f 2 3 4
```

(Since there is not yet any bug for the `type == 'f'` part, I did not include it here.)

And I'm executing the real mesh simplification in the following code block.

```
void Mesh::simplifyMesh(const char* input, const char* output, int faceCnt) {
    //  You may assume inputs are always valid.
    loadMF(input);
    std::cout << "Original face count: " << F.size() << std::endl;

    print((*V[0]).x);
    print((*V[1]).x);
    print((*V[2]).x);
    print((*V[3]).x);

    //  And other fanciful stuff.
    //  So on, omitted here.
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use `print` to debug here. The bug I'm having is that although for the `print` statement in the `loadMF` function (i.e. `print(v->x)`), it successfully prints the different x values out, for the `print` statement in the `simplifyMesh` function, it only prints the last x value. That is, it prints 3.020618 for consecutively four times. And no matter how many `V`s I have in the .mesh file, it always only print the last number.

I have also included the Vertex definition if it helps.

```
struct Vertex {
    //  3D coordinates.
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
}
```

Anybody has any idea how to solve this bug?

Comment: `Vertex* v; ss >> v->x >> v->y >> v->z;` Here, `v` is an uninitialized pointer, pointing to some random memory address. You are then reading into that memory, which would either crash your program or, worse, corrupt some random data.

Comment: What if I use `Vertex v; ss >> v.x >> v.y >> v.z;`? Is that initialised?

Comment: Yes, this part would work. This moves the problem further down: what do you plan to do with `v` next?

Comment: Since `Vertex` is a relatively small type with low copy cost, I would suggest creating a `vector<Vertex>` (stores copies of elements) instead of a `Vector<Vertex*>` (stores pointers to externally allocated vertices), which saves you the hassle of manual memory management.

Comment: I have tried this, but it seems that the content from the file is still not loaded into `v` properly. Same bug persists.

Comment: You used `getline`, but then later used `operator<<` for the string stream, expecting the same effect as `getline` (`operator>>` and `operator<<` stop at whitespace). Just use a `std::istringstream` and initialize it with the string.

Comment: Yup, but I have chosen to use pointers because I think the algorithm I'm trying to implement will need it. In that case, does 'manual memory management' refer to something like `delete pointerToV`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must do

```
 Vertex *v = new Vertex();
```

before you try to store values into v. 
Your class (or struct) Vertex should have a constructor (even an empty one) and this should solve it.

Comment: Amazing. Only your answer solves my problem after I have seen so many other solutions - great thanks.